# Как поменять строки местами?

Tags: python-3.x

Помогите, пожалуйста, реализовать следующую программу:

> Необходимо подавать строки на вход по очереди, а по завершению подачи
> строк, они должны быть выведены в обратном порядке.

Собственно два вопроса:

1. Можно ли как-то по-другому реализовать выход из циклического ввода, кроме как по слову?
2. Как можно поменять строки местами?

Вот мой кусочек кода:

```
a = ''
while True:
    l = input()
    if l == 'end':
        break
    else:
        a += l + '\n'
print(a)
```

Заранее большое спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. > Можно ли как-то по-другому реализовать выход из циклического ввода, кроме как по слову?

   Обычный подход — тест на пустую строку (пользователь уже не задает ничего, только нажмёт клавишу <kbd>Enter</kbd>).
2. > Как можно поменять строки местами?

   Методом `.reverse()` списка — значит, надо сделать из заданных строк их список.

---

Всё вместе:

```
PROMPT = 'Введите очередное слово (или только нажмите клавишу Enter для окончания)'
lst = []

while True:
    word = input(PROMPT).strip()     # strip() удалит пробелы перед/за вводимым текстом
    if word:                         # не надо  «word == ''»,  но может быть
        lst.append(word)
    else:
        break;
        
lst.reverse()
for word in lst:
    print(word)
```

Comment: вместо цикла в конце можно просто `print(*lst, sep='\n')`

Answer (score 0):

Можно реализовать рекурсией:

```
def f():
    s = input()
    if s != 'end':
        f()
        print(s)


f()
```

---

> Можно ли как-то по-другому реализовать выход из циклического ввода,
> кроме как по слову?

Можно определять конец ввода по пустой строке. Или заранее указать количество строк (первым аргументом скрипту).

Comment: Лучше учить, как избавляться от рекурсии, а не как создавать её там, где можно обойтись и без неё )